# combining fgets/scanf and switch to read a character

Tags: c, switch-statement

I would like to create a kind of menu. I will enter a character and depending on what character some text will be printed. The problem for me lies in the default option in the code bellow. I want it to recognize everything that is not 1, 2, 3 or q. Not just characters, but strings as well. If the input is "sf<ssad", I do not want it to print "Invalid input" 7 times, only once. Additionally, if I enter "qf<<dsc", even though the first character is valid, I want to count the whole input as invalid since it is more than one character. Similarly, an input like "1sd<j" should not print the result "hello". Instead it should print it as "Invalid input".

I want a reliable code that preferably does not include scanf and is easy on the eyes. I tried the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
char cmd;

do {
    printf("Enter 1 to print hello, enter 2 to print world, enter 3 to print hello world and enter q to quit\n");
    printf("Enter: ");
    scanf(" %c", &cmd);

    switch(cmd) {
       case '1' : printf("hello\n"); break;
       case '2' : printf("world\n"); break;
       case '3' : printf("hello world\n"); break;
       case 'q' : printf("Exiting...\n"); break;
       default : printf("Invalid input!\n"); break; 
    }
} while(cmd!='q');

return 0;
}
```

This is not sufficient since if I enter "sf<ssad", "Invalid input" will be printed 7 times. I tried some other versions but they had similar problems. One idea I have is to use fgets, and then take the first character and then use atoi, although I am not sure what it would look like. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you need to use `atoi()`? Just use `switch(line[0])` and test it the same way you currently do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `fgets()`, check for error, and then set `cmd` to the first character of the line. Then the rest of your code is the same.

```
char line[100];
char cmd;
do {
    printf("Enter 1 to print hello, enter 2 to print world, enter 3 to print hello world and enter q to quit\n");
    printf("Enter: ");
    char *res = fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);
    if (!res) {
        break;
    }

    cmd = line[0];
    switch(cmd) {
       case '1' : printf("hello\n"); break;
       case '2' : printf("world\n"); break;
       case '3' : printf("hello world\n"); break;
       case 'q' : printf("Exiting...\n"); break;
       default : printf("Invalid input!\n"); break; 
    }

} while (cmd != 'q');
```

Comment: I forgot to mention this, but I also do not want an input like "qsf<dsf" to print "Exiting...", or "3d<fdsf" to print "hello world". Although the first character is correct, if you have entered more than one character, then it should it count as invalid input. I will make an edit in my post...

Comment: You can check `strlen(line)` to see if it's more than 1 character. But don't forget that it also contains a newline, so the normal length will be 2.

Comment: Or you could use `strcmp()` to compare the entire line with your options.

Comment: When I use strlen(line) it always says that size=100

Comment: That shouldn't happen after `fgets()` returns successfully.

Comment: I copied your code and entered printf("%d", sizeof(line)); right before the cmd=line[0], and the output is still 100

Comment: `sizeof` is not `strlen`

Comment: That is true indeed. My apologies for the misunderstanding. I tried it now and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> If the input is "sf<ssad", I do not want it to print "Invalid input" 7 times, only once.

In that case, you should read an entire line of input at once, instead of one character at once. For this, I recommend that you use the function `fgets` instead of `scanf`.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void get_line_from_user( const char prompt[], char buffer[], int buffer_size );

int main( void )
{
    bool quit = false;

    while ( !quit )
    {
        char line[200];

        //print menu
        printf(
            "Menu:\n"
            "Enter 1 to print hello,\n"
            "enter 2 to print world,\n"
            "enter 3 to print hello world,\n"
            "or enter q to quit\n"
        );

        //get one line of input from the user
        get_line_from_user( "Enter choice: ", line, sizeof line );

        //verify that user entered exactly one character
        if ( line[0] == '\0' || line[1] != '\0' )
        {
            printf( "Error: Please only enter a single character!\n\n" );
            continue;
        }

        switch( line[0] )
        {
            case '1':
                printf( "hello\n" );
                break;
            case '2':
                printf( "world\n" );
                break;
            case '3':
                printf( "hello world\n" );
                break;
            case 'q':
                printf( "Exiting...\n" );
                quit = true;
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid input!\n");
        }

        //add spacing
        printf( "\n" );
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

//This function will read exactly one line of input from the
//user. It will remove the newline character, if it exists. If
//the line is too long to fit in the buffer, then the function
//will automatically reprompt the user for input. On failure,
//the function will never return, but will print an error
//message and call "exit" instead.
void get_line_from_user( const char prompt[], char buffer[], int buffer_size )
{
    for (;;) //infinite loop, equivalent to while(1)
    {
        char *p;

        //prompt user for input
        fputs( prompt, stdout );

        //attempt to read one line of input
        if ( fgets( buffer, buffer_size, stdin ) == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Error reading from input!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //attempt to find newline character
        p = strchr( buffer, '\n' );

        //make sure that entire line was read in (i.e. that
        //the buffer was not too small to store the entire line)
        if ( p == NULL )
        {
            int c;

            //a missing newline character is ok if the next
            //character is a newline character or if we have
            //reached end-of-file (for example if the input is
            //being piped from a file or if the user enters
            //end-of-file in the terminal itself)
            if ( (c=getchar()) != '\n' && !feof(stdin) )
            {
                if ( c == EOF )
                {
                    printf( "Error reading from input!\n" );
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }

                printf( "Input was too long to fit in buffer!\n" );

                //discard remainder of line
                do
                {
                    c = getchar();

                    if ( c == EOF )
                    {
                        //this error message will be printed if either
                        //a stream error or an unexpected end-of-file
                        //is encountered
                        printf( "Error reading from input!\n" );
                        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                    }

                } while ( c != '\n' );

                //reprompt user for input by restarting loop
                continue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //remove newline character by overwriting it with
            //null character
            *p = '\0';
        }

        //input was ok, so break out of loop
        break;
    }
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
Menu:
Enter 1 to print hello,
enter 2 to print world,
enter 3 to print hello world,
or enter q to quit
Enter choice: sf<ssad
Error: Please only enter a single character!

Menu:
Enter 1 to print hello,
enter 2 to print world,
enter 3 to print hello world,
or enter q to quit
Enter choice: qsf<dsf
Error: Please only enter a single character!

Menu:
Enter 1 to print hello,
enter 2 to print world,
enter 3 to print hello world,
or enter q to quit
Enter choice: 1
hello

Menu:
Enter 1 to print hello,
enter 2 to print world,
enter 3 to print hello world,
or enter q to quit
Enter choice: 2
world

Menu:
Enter 1 to print hello,
enter 2 to print world,
enter 3 to print hello world,
or enter q to quit
Enter choice: 3
hello world

Menu:
Enter 1 to print hello,
enter 2 to print world,
enter 3 to print hello world,
or enter q to quit
Enter choice: q
Exiting...
```

Comment: `get_line_from_user()` has 2 pedantic corner case failures: 1) `if ( ferror(stdin) )` errantly reports "Error reading from input!\n" when `ferror(stdin)` is true due to the error flag set before calling `get_line_from_user()`.  Easy to fix.  2) `strchr( buffer, '\n' );` fails to find the `'\n'` if a preceding _null character_ was read.  Hard to fix.

Comment: Sample simplification: `if (p == NULL) { bool extra = false; int ch; while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) { extra = true; } if (ch == EOF && !feof(stdin)) { printf("Error reading from input!\n"); exit( EXIT_FAILURE); }  if (extra) { printf("Input was too long to fit in buffer!\n");  } continue;  }`

Comment: @chux: I won't address the second issue you mentioned (embedded null characters), because that is a general issue with all functions in the C standard library that use null-terminated strings. Therefore, that issue is not specific to my code. However, regarding the first issue, I believe I have fixed it (see my edit) by not using the function `ferror` at all anymore, but by only using the function `feof` and by checking for the return value `EOF`. I am assuming that if `EOF` is returned and if `feof` is false, then the `EOF` must be due to a stream error.